# Compiling glew32s.lib for MinGW?

Tags: c, windows, opengl, static-linking, glew

I can't find any information on compiling glew32s.lib for MinGW. I followed this tutorial: https://bruceoutdoors.wordpress.com/2014/07/16/glew-for-mingw-in-windows/

The GLEW website provides the libraries, but not for MinGW. I would like to statically link GLEW with -lglew32s, but I can't find any information anywhere about compiling the static library for use with MinGW? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

That's strange. By renaming libglew32.a to libglew32s.a, it now links statically without a problem.